# What is the meaning of the saying "two Jews, three opinions?"

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, number, aphorisms-adages

There is an old saying that goes something like "ask two Jews, you'll get three opinions."  What is the meaning of it?  More specifically, why the numbers two and three, as opposed to "ask two Jews, you'll get two opinions", or "ask one Jew, you'll get two opinions"?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for the interesting question which, unfortunately, is off-topic. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including its 57 questions tagged ["machlokes"](/tags/machlokes/info).

Comment: @msh210 I thought it might be off-topic, but asked anyway.  Ask X Jews, get 0 answers.  ;)

Comment: Heh, sorry. Maybe [english.se]? Explicitly [on-topic there](//english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is "Etymology (history of words’ development)"; I don't know whether that includes provenance of aphorisms.

Comment: It would be that once you get two Jews speaking the two of them start analyzing the full set of cases. See discussions of why it is better to have a chavrusa

Comment: I think that there is an answer which is appropriate for this site. The idea that talmudic tradition establishes a practice of providing a variety of voices and understandings, which even leads to multiple versions of any position (thus more answers than participants), coupled with the general talmudic practice of recording arguments and differences of opinion on most every topic makes that "2 Jews, 3 opinions" relevant to an understanding of Judaic logic and rhetorical methodology, much like "why do Jews answer a question with a question."

Comment: @msh210 Any chance of reopening based on previous comments?  I'd like to accept Danno's comment as an answer.

Comment: Generally, we don't say a question is on-topic because it has an on-topic answer, and I don't see why this should be an exception. heenenee, I recommend asking at EL&U or bringing this issue to [meta] or [chat]; others, if you wish to vote to reopen, of course that option is open to you. cc @Danno

Comment: I would assume that if the question can be worded as something not focused in the linguistics, but in the potential for theological underpinnings, it could be worthy of reopening.

Comment: I never heard that expression relating to all Jews, just "Israelis".  When I landed in Israel on Election Day a number of years ago, I heard it used a few times during political discussions on the plane, but a LOT more after landing.  It seemed to be an expression of pride and general good-will.

Comment: @Gary: definitely used for more than just Israelis; popular among Soviet Jews as well.

As to the original question - why 2 and 3, I'll give a mathematical answer: because 2 and 3 are relatively prime, which creates an ambiguity. Does one of the Jews hold two opinions? Or they both hold two, but one coincides? Or only one of them does, but which one, you don't know? Or both of them kind of agree with something else at the same time, having "half" on opinion in addition to the extra one?

See, this version made you think and wonder - which is why it was shaped this way, and persisted.

Comment: @Romwell  thanks for the clues!  I figured it was an Israeli expression, sort of like when my brother-in-law pointed to construction going on and said "see--our national bird, the crane".  Btw, there's no "relatively", 2 & 3 are plain old prime numbers.  I guess they'd skip the nonprime 4 and the next step would be "3 Jews, 5 opinions".  But 2/3 does make you think of your suggestions and more, like is the 3rd opinion that of the elephant in the room, or the Bat Kol our forefathers ignored in the oven story, etc..

Comment: @Gary: glad my comment was of help.

By the way, when I said "relatively prime", this is what it means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers

As such, 3 and 4 are also relatively prime.